# Different response time between a GET and GET-NEXT operation (pysnmp)

Tags: python, time, pysnmp

I'm using Python with `PySNMP`. I noticed a different behaviour (about response time) between a `GET` operation on a non-existing element and a `GET-NEXT` operation which targets a non-existing element. It this a known problem? Has someone tried to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Please do not use hashtags in the title. You only need tags (which you have, good).

Comment: Are you using pysnmp as a manager or agent? More likely it is the agent being slow finding proper OID for GETNEXT response.

Comment: I'm using it as agent. Do you have some hint about ? I would try to fix it, if it is possible.

Thank you again.

Comment: Is it for the first GETNEXT (when pysnmp builds an index internally) or it happen every time? In general GETNEXT performs slower as it needs to find "next" OID. You could implement your own MibInstrumentationController backed by a no/SQL database if you want to take the matter into your own hands. ;)

Comment: It seems it happen every time I do a GET-NEXT, so if I do a GET-BULK and a group of oids does not exist, I have to wait a lot of time before getting the answer.
It's an edit I can do using pysnmp as black-box or I must edit your library ?